# No embedded point spectra for (discrete) Schrodinger operators with compactly supported potential

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

Consider the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and let $H_0$ denote the (negative) Laplacian on $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ with spectrum $[-2d,2d]$. Suppose that I add a potential $q:\mathbb{Z}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and consider $H=H_0+q$. Then if $q$ has compact support, is the intersection of $(-2d,2d)$ and the point spectrum of $H$ empty? I know the result holds for $d=1$ from a paper of SN Naboko, SI Yakovlev (in fact it holds if $q$ decays fast enough) but I want to know if it is true (and gain a reference for it) for $d>1$.

Comment: I haven't found exactly the result you're looking for, but this paper, if it's correct, shows that the behavior changes for $d\ge 5$: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0522.pdf.  In particular, they show that the point spectrum is exactly $\{2d\}$ (a single eigenvalue on the boundary of the essential spectrum) for a delta potential of critical strength.  It would seem plausible that the point spectrum for *two* well-separated delta potentials of that strength would then be two eigenvalues, one just outside and one just inside the essential spectrum.  But you'd have to check.

Comment: That's interesting to know. I'm not bothered about eigenvalues on the edges though.